# Android: Licencing sample app works but integration doesn't

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've just finished designing a small android app and have now come to a point where i want to license this app and add it to the android market. I've implemented the LVL without any problems but when i come to test the licensing i am always getting the response "NOT_LICENSED" even though in the developer panel i have set the response to "LICENSED". I then uploaded the sample licensing app through the developers panel and tested it, this works fine and returns whatever i set the response to be.

I have copied and pasted the whole sample project into my existing project and am still getting the same response. Is there something i am missing?

My app in the developers panel is unpublished but still it should return a licensed response shouldn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this wasn't working but i found a way to fix it anyway. I had to remove my app from the market then re-add it.